# Get programmatic info on threads using gdb and pthreads

Tags: c, gdb

Using gdb, I can type 'info threads' or 'thread apply all backtrace' to get a listing of all my threads and what they're doing.

I would like to write a gdb macro which will instead list all running threads. This macro would retrieve the thread number (i.e. the argument to the gdb 'thread' command) and then would get the name of the thread that I have defined and stored in thread-local storage.

In pseudocode, this would look something like:

```
for each thread in threads
    t thread
    f 1
    set $name = my_name
    f top
    printf "Thread %d has name %s and is currently doing %s\n", thread, $name, curr_frame
next
```

There may be some small complexity around getting the string for curr_frame, but I'm willing to elide that for right now if I could get a good framework going for the rest of this bit.

I have a list of threads in my program, and for it I can get the pthread_t which corresponds to the thread pointer displayed as part of 'info thread' output:

```
(gdb) info thread
....
30 Thread 0x5221c940 (LWP 25304)  0x00000031c5a0aee9 in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
....
(gdb) p *(_thread_t*)my_threads[0].pid
$4 = {
  t_id = 0x5221c940,
```

As you can see, the t_id member is the same as the thread address in the output, but I can't really find any way to take programmatic advantage of this fact.

Anybody know a way to do this?

Comment: Can you locate the memory address of the base of an individual thread's stack and utilize an offset from that?

Comment: Doesn't `thread apply all bt full` help you?

Comment: @Nikolai - Nope! The goal is to not have to parse through 70 threads' worth of backtraces.

Comment: @JAB - Probably not, unless you know of a good way to get this by grubbing around in the internals of pthread_t.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with version 7.0, GDB is scriptable in python, so you could pretty much implement your pseudo-code as is. See the documentation for accessing threads [here](http://sourceware.org/gdb/download/onlinedocs/gdb/Threads-In-Python.html#Threads-In-Python) and for getting the stack frame [here](http://sourceware.org/gdb/download/onlinedocs/gdb/Frames-In-Python.html#Frames-In-Python).

I think easiest is to write your program in a `source.py` file and then run in GDB:

```
source source.py
```

Comment: That is the eventual answer, yes. Sadly, we're not on gdb 7 yet.

Comment: While Python scripting was added in GDB 7.0, Python thread support was only added in GDB 7.2. With GDB 7.3, on Linux, 'info thread' will display thread name automagically (if the application sets it via PR_SET_NAME prctl() call)